# Change word document style with an app for Office

Tags: javascript, office365-apps, apps-for-office

Im trying to create an app for Word Office using the Office js API.

I have found how to get and set content into the word document but Im having a hard time finding how to change things like Styles (Headings, etc.)

Before getting into how to do it, is it even possible?

Comment: Using setSelectedDataAsync API, you should be able to pass it HTML or Office Open XML which both support styling, so I'm confused here. What exactly are you trying to accomplish that can't be done with the two APIs you've mentioned?

Comment: When I wrote this question what I wanted was an API to use Word predefined styles and use them on the selected text just as a normal user does. Anyways, I ended up inserting ooxml and got the work done.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to you question is yes and now, the word api is a bit new and missing some functionalities which may make a developer life easier.  First, headers are not supported in the word api,  a work around for this is to create a Content control and use it as a header.  I am currently using this work around in a word app that I use.

Now for styles, styles are awesome to use.  If a user's pc currently have those styles installed on their pc you can easily reference those styles.  However, as a developer you may have found out that life is not easy.  So I too ran int this issue and approached it by first inserting my desired content, then making a collection of paragraphs proxy object.  I then load both both objects, and sync.  After I iterate through the collection of paragraphs and add my custom styles which is an preset object which I made.  the following function will show you what I tried to explain.  I hope this help

```
    function InsertHtml(content, styleSelection) {

    Word.run(function (context) {

        var range = context.document.body.insertHtml(content, "end");
        var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            var index = $.map(headerStyles, function (obj, index) {
                if (obj.name == styleSelection) {
                    return index;
                }
            })
            for (var x = 0; x < paragraphs.items.length; x++) {

                var paragraph = paragraphs.items[x];
                paragraph.font.name = headerStyles[index].fontName;
                paragraph.font.color = headerStyles[index].color;
                paragraph.font.size = headerStyles[index].size;
                paragraph.leftIndent = headerStyles[index].indent;
                //paragraph.lineSpacing = headerStyles[index].lineSpacing;
                //paragraph.alignment = headerStyles[index].alignment;                          
            }



            return context.sync();
        });
    })
    .catch(feedBackMessage);
};
```

Comment: Hi. I have one question about your answer. You custom style is a preset object which you made. Can you please elaborate. I want to add custom styles to a document using my word javascript add-in. I am not sure how to proceed. It would be great help if you could explain a bit more.

Comment: Hey Mohamed, are the custom styles loaded on the PC? This example is when I was working with HTML and was able to alter the styles by having a css class I could reference.  A good place to start is by creating your styles locally on your PC, write a paragraph or a few sentences with those styles, and then proceed to read it in as HTML using the JavaScript function.  Once you load the text as HTML you can see the output created and how the css classes are made to house the style.  You can then mimic this behavior to add custom styles.